# Nodejs application healthcheck best practice

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes-health-check

I'm looking into setting up a healthcheck mechanism for nodejs microservices running via container orchestrations. From a nodejs/express point of view, what is considered best practice to ensure that the service is indeed running on a given port on a given container? Eg. A healthcheck middleware or particular nodejs library, using a separate service port etc.

Comment: PM2 might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Answer (score 2):

In order to implement healthcheck in nodejs, use the following

use express-healthcheck as a dependency in your nodejs project
in your app.js or equivalent code, use the following line

app.use('/healthcheck', require('express-healthcheck')());
if your app is up your response will be like
{
  "uptime":23.09
}

also it returns a status code of 200
Hope this helps

Comment: can you help me with healthcheck servers?